# memory leak caused by pthread

Tags: c++, memory, pthreads

I'm working on a project in c++, and i'm using pthread. by using task manager i can notice that my application has a memory leak.

```
using namespace std;
int main()
{
        while(true){
            try{
                Foo * foo = new Foo(args ...);
                pthread_create(0,NULL,&Foo::doSomthing,NULL);
                pthread_join(0 ,NULL);
                delete foo;
            }catch (const std::bad_alloc&) {
              throw "";
            }
            Sleep(10);
            system("cls");
}
    return 0;
}
```

but if i call the function directly the memory leak gone

```
using namespace std;
int main()
{
        while(true){
            try{
                Foo * foo = new Foo(args ...);
                foo->doSomthing();
                delete foo;
            }catch (const std::bad_alloc&) {
              throw "";           
            }
            Sleep(10);
            system("cls");
}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use pthreads in C++. Use [std::thread](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread).

Comment: thaks for your answer but the probleme stay the same.i want to khow what's happen exactely.

Comment: there is nothing wrong in **doSmthing** method,i maked it empty and the probleme persist

Answer (score 1):

I have reduced the example down to

```
#include <pthread.h>

void* doSomthing(void *)
{
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        pthread_create(0, NULL, doSomthing, NULL);
        pthread_join(0, NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

There is no memory allocation in the user code. The program still leaks.

`pthread_create` expects a pointer to a `pthread_t` as the first parameter. This pointer will be used as an opaque pthread handle and initialized according to the internal implementation of `pthread_create`. We don't know what happens in here. We do not need to know. Frankly, we don't want to know because that kind of information ruins the abstraction and thus portability.

The asker's code call `pthread_create` with 0. 0 will be treated as NULL, meaning `pthread_create` will be operating on a NULL pointer. That's classic [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Don't do this. On Windows (MinGW with g++ 4.8) this appears to result in the thread running, the `pthread_join` failing (always check the return value!), and a large memory leak. In Linux, this appears to be instantly fatal.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>

void* doSomthing(void *)
{
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        pthread_t threadhandle;
        if (!pthread_create(&threadhandle, NULL, doSomthing, NULL))
        {
            if (pthread_join(threadhandle, NULL))
            {
                std::cerr << "Join fail\n";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            std::cerr << "Create fail\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Providing a pointer to a valid thread handle does not leak. Checking for and reporting on errors helps you debug and manage unexpected failures. This second approach should work for you.

Comment: i tried that piece of code. Unfortunately it's not working and i still have the same probleme. try to test it by your own , and you 'll find tha there is a memory leak . you can use task manager as i do

Comment: I have run both code examples. The first leaks. The second does not. If the second example leaks when you run it, the leak is in code you have no control over.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing 0 as the first argument to `pthread_join()`, so you are never joining the threads that are created.  This is where you are leaking memory.

You need to join the thread you created:

```
pthread_t thread;
pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &Foo::doSomthing, NULL);
pthread_join(thread, NULL);
```